# How to pattern match an ADT in ML

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, ml

I'm brand new to ML and I'm trying to figure out the syntax for pattern matching.
Can someone help me understand the compiler error, and the correct syntax for pattern matching an `AssignStm` while binding its second argument to the variable `e` ?

Maybe what I'm trying to do is simply not supported?  I have an ADT defined as follows.

```ml
type id = string

datatype binop = Plus | Minus | Times | Div

datatype stm = CompoundStm of stm * stm
             | AssignStm of id * exp
             | PrintStm of exp list

     and exp = IdExp of id
             | NumExp of int
             | OpExp of exp * binop * exp
             | EseqExp of stm * exp
```

And I'm trying to implement a function which counts the number of calls to `print` in a given statement.

The compiler complains

```
/Users/jimka/Repos/mciml/fig4.1.sml:15.60 Error: unbound variable or constructor: e
```

Here is my code:

```ml
fun maxints(a,b) =
    if a > b then a else b

fun maxargs PrintStm nil = 0 
  | maxargs PrintStm h::t = 1 + (maxargs printStm t )
  | maxargs CompoundStm(a,b) =  maxints(maxargs a, maxargs b)
  | maxargs AssignStm(_,e: exp) = maxargs e        (* the error is on this line *)
  | maxargs IdExp = 0 
  | maxargs NumExp = 0
  | maxargs OpExp(e1,_,e2) = maxints(maxargs e1, maxargs e2)
  | maxargs EseqExp(s,e) = maxints(maxargs s, maxargs e)
```

The actual code which triggers the error is the following:

```ml
val prog =
    CompoundStm(AssignStm("a",OpExp(NumExp 5, Plus, NumExp e)),
                CompoundStm(AssignStm("b",
                                      EseqExp(PrintStm[IdExp"a", OpExp(IdExp"a", Minus,
                                                                       NumExp 1)],
                                              OpExp(NumExp 10, Times IdExp"a"))),
                            PrintStm[IdExp "b"]))


maxargs prog
```

molbdnilo suggested the following.  But I get the same error.

```ml
fun maxargs( PrintStm nil) = 0 
  | maxargs( PrintStm (h::t)) = 1 + maxints(maxargs(h), maxargs( PrintStm( t )))
  | maxargs( CompoundStm (a,b)) =  maxints(maxargs( a), maxargs( b))
  | maxargs( AssignStm (_,e)) = maxargs( e)
  | maxargs( IdExp (_)) = 0 
  | maxargs( NumExp (_)) = 0
  | maxargs( OpExp (e1,_,e2)) = maxints(maxargs e1, maxargs e2)
  | maxargs( EseqExp (s,e)) = maxints( maxargs(s),  maxargs(e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is not a pattern-matching problem, but that `prog` contains `NumExp e` while you haven't defined `e` anywhere.

You also have the problem that you're trying to make `maxargs` take either a `stm` or an `exp`, and you can't do that.

Also,

```
fun maxargs PrintStm nil = 0
```

would define a function that takes two arguments; `PrintStm` and `nil`.

You need parentheses around the patterns, and you need two mutually recursive functions:

```
fun maxargs_stm (PrintStm nil) = 0 
  | maxargs_stm (PrintStm (h::t)) = 1 + (maxargs_stm (PrintStm t))
  | maxargs_stm (CompoundStm(a,b)) =  maxints(maxargs_stm a, maxargs_stm b)
  | maxargs_stm (AssignStm(_,e: exp)) = maxargs_exp e
and maxargs_exp (IdExp _) = 0 
  | maxargs_exp (NumExp _) = 0
  | maxargs_exp (OpExp(e1,_,e2)) = maxints(maxargs_exp e1, maxargs_exp e2)
  | maxargs_exp (EseqExp(s,e)) = maxints(maxargs_stm s, maxargs_exp e);
```

Comment: hmm.  Sadly, that doesn't seem to help.  I get the same error after that change.

Comment: I'll update the original post to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: ahhh, `prog` contains `NumExp e`.  I see now,  I was totally looking at the `e` in the pattern match.   Thanks.

Comment: The next that I can't define `maxargs` to accept either `stm` or `exp` was not obvious.  I supposed that is simply a feature of the language.

However, could I somehow define type `entity` to be `stm | exp` ?   Thus `maxargs` would then map `entity` to `int` ?  I.e. does `|` only work with constructors or does it also word with type names?

Comment: If you want a union type like that, you could define a new datatype and a constructor for each option, though I'm of the opinion two mutually recursive functions (as molbdnilo presents) is the better solution.